# Generating Entity Framework model from DB without Navigation Properties

Tags: entity-framework-4

I have a database where many of the tables have createdBy/modifiedBy columns that are foreign keys into a User table.  When I update my model from the database, it generates navigation properties for all of these relationships.  The User entity ends up with dozens of collections to navigate these relationships.

When I update the model from the database, I have the option to "Include foreign key columns in the model".  If I un-check it, I get the navigation properties, but not the foreign key fields.  Is there a way to generate the opposite, keep the foreign key fields, but don't add the navigation properties?

I'm new to Entity Framework, so I apologize if my question highlights my ignorance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is not such option. You must manually delete navigation properties from `User` entity. It should not add them again once you update model from database.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I don't suppose there is any way to hide the User entity in the Visual Studio Designer?  Actually, I want to hide all the associations to the User entity, because it makes a mess of the model...

Answer (score 0):

This is a painful situation - currently when I update the model from db and add a new table all the pesky navigation properties come back. Does anyone else have an idea of how to strip out all the FK references and Navigation properties?

The closest answer I have found is customizing the T4 code generation here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2009/01/22/customizing-entity-classes-with-t4.aspx